# Issues configuring oracle java 6 plugin in chromium

Tags: java, chromium, oracle

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get Oracle Java running in Chromium.  My Java version is shown below:

```
java version "1.6.0_32"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_32-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.7-b02, mixed mode)
```

In my bash_profile I have:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32 
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin 4
```

I've tried linking as below:

```
ln -s $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins
```

I had it working and then upgraded to 12.04, and am now stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I used to link the `libnpjp2.so` as `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so` and `~/.mozilla/plugins/`

EDIT: 
[Where to download and how to install the sun java plugin](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java)

Comment: No difference.  I tried starting with --enable-plugins also, but still no sigh of Java in about:plugins.

Comment: I'd be happy if I could get it working in Firefox either.

Comment: @TomEustace : I added the link from where I found the detailled explanations to install sun  java plugin.

Comment: ok, I had the plugin enabled for jre 1.7.04 in chromium by following the instructions. I now just need to get it working for jre 1.6.32 as that is what I require.  jre 1.7.04 was located in /opt/java/64. I am using a 64 bit system but require 32 bit jre.

Comment: I have purged openjdk. I now have only oracle jdk 1.6.32 installed.  I run the various commands to link to Java plugin but still not working.  Java is installed at /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32.  I've updated alternatives to point to this version.  I must be missing something!!

Comment: @TomEustace : your problems seems related to a 32/64 bit problem, I'm not sure a 64bits chromium could load a 32 bit java plugin... Try to install [`ia32-libs` to allow the compatiblity 64/32 bits](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ia32-libs)

Comment: Appreciate the help, but unfortunately no change after installing ia32-libs.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working by running the commands from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130473/could-anyone-provide-a-step-by-step-for-getting-juniper-netconnect-and-citrix) for amd64

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox openjdk-6-jdk icedtea-6-plugin
sudo apt-get install firefox:i386 openjdk-6-jdk:i386 icedtea-6-plugin:i386
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm assuming you're the same person as the OP, if so, please accept this answer to mark this post as solved. Thank you.